# Cache a variable temporarily or for few minutes

Tags: java, database, caching

How to cache a variable temporarily or for few minutes in Java?

I need to use a variable temporarily for few minutes as hitting the database always will cause huge performance impact.

The problem is I have a db configuration value which can be changed by user. Such a change needs to be captured without re-starting the server.

So finding an option on how to cache a variable temporarily or for few minutes in Java. so that after 5 or 10 minutes interval we can constantly clear the cache.

Comment: Such solutions already exist. Search for "java database cache". Read. Pick a suitable approach. (If you're handling this manually, it *usually* indicates too much work.)

Comment: Could always just cache the results in a text file.

Comment: You could look at the Weak Reference (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html), java will keep it till the next Garbage Collection (assuming there are no References) or one of the cache packages if more control is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Most of Cache Framework is able to configure the livetime of the cache.

If you are using [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/) for example, the configuration would be something like this :
Note that 300 refer to 5 minutes

```
<cache name="testCache1"
 eternal="false"
 timeToLiveSeconds="300"
 overflowToDisk="true"
 diskPersistent="true"
 diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="300"
 maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000"
/>
```

In case user make change the configuration,and the system able to detect it, you could also invalidate the cache.

```
CacheManager manager = CacheManager.getInstance();
cache = manager.getCache(cacheName);
cache.remove(key);

or 

cache.removeAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something from JCF.

How about `LinkedHashMap` and customizing `removeEldestEntry` .

Caveat being that method is invoked only on puts.